# How do I upload a excel spreadsheet into existing table using coldfusion?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do I upload a excel spreadsheet into existing table using ColdFusion10?
I have an an excel spreadsheet that has been saved and I have CFQuery ("myQuery") that outputs the data I need. How do I loop through the query and import into an existing table?

Database: MS SQL Server

Thus far, I understand that I need to loop through the query I have that has all the data.

```
    <cffunction name="uploadDogSheet" access="public" output="yes" returnType="void" 
    hint="upload the spreadSheet">

<cfset currentRowChecked = "1"> 
<cfset lastRow = numberOfRows> <!-- sets the number of rows that it will validate-->


    <cfspreadsheet
    action="read"
    src="#SESSION.theExcelFile#"
    headerrow= "1"
    excludeHeaderRow = "true"
    query = "allDoggyData"
    rows = "1-#lastRow#" />     


    <cfscript>    

        allDataQuery = new Query(
        sql ="SELECT * FROM allDoggyData",
        dbtype = "query",
        allData = allData);
        allDataQueryResult = allDataQuery.execute().getResult();
    </cfscript> 




    <cfloop query="allDoggyData">

<CFQUERY DATASOURCE="#mydatabase#" name="input_req">
insert into temp_dog_upload (dogNameColumn, dogBreedColumn, dogColor)
          values
(
<cfqueryparam value="#allDoggyData.dogNameExcelColumn#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
<cfqueryparam value="#allDoggyData.dogBreedExcelColumn#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
<cfqueryparam value="#allDoggyData.dogColorExcelColumn#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
)               
</CFQUERY>

</cfloop>

<p>The sheet has been uploaded!<p></span>
```

Comment: What database are you using? MSSQL, MYSQL or?

Comment: Database: MS SQL Server

Comment: Why not just use the 'Import Data' task in Management Studio?

Comment: I have an upload interface from a website were users can upload their spreadsheet. I'm reading that spreadsheet using CFSPREADSHEET and also have a CFQUERY that contains all the data.

Comment: You are making the assumption you must loop, which may not be the case. Do a search for "sql server import spreadsheet" first. There are a number of options, most of them not involving loops. For example, a five second search turned up http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686

Comment: The cfscript is for testing.

Comment: Nobody said anything about cfscript (not on this thread anyway). The point of the sample link above is that if you do a little research, you will find there are more efficient options than looping available in SQL Server.

Comment: @Leigh My comment in regards to cfscript was not in response to you. It was a comment I posted in case anyone was wondering why the cfscript was there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking is pretty simple. Upload the spreadsheet to your sever then use cfspreadsheet to read it.

```
<cfspreadsheet  
action="read" 
src = "filepath" 
columns = "range" 
columnnames = "comma-delimited list" 
excludeHeaderRow = "true | false" 
format = "CSV|HTML" 
headerrow = "row number" 
name = "text" 
query = "query name" 
rows = "range" 
sheet = "number" 
sheetname = "text">
```

Then simply loop through the query that you defined in the cfspreadsheet

```
<cfloop query="queryname">

    <cfquery name="" datasource="">
       INSERT INTO ....
    </cfquery

</cfloop>
```

P.S. This was my answer BEFORE you deleted the post and I was no longer able to submit my answer.

Comment: This is what I have currently, bul I get an 'error executing database query' error:                                      <CFQUERY DATASOURCE="#mydatabase#" name="required_db">                                                insert into temp_dog_upload (dogNameColumn, dogBreedColumn)         values
(
<cfqueryparam value="#alldoggyQueryResult.dogNameColumnFrom#">                        <cfqueryparam value="#alldoggyQueryResult.dogBreedColumn#">              )
    </CFQUERY>

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact error and the exact code you are using? Including the loop and cfspreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches to take.  They both have one very important detail in common.  Put the spreadsheet data into a staging table first.  Process and validate as required first, and then write to your main tables from your staging table.

Method 1 is to have your web page accept files from your users and put them somewhere.  Then, write an SSIS package that looks for these files, loads them into your staging table, and carrys on until the job is done.  Then write an agent to schedule this job to run at the appropriate interval.

Method 2 is to use continue with ColdFusion.  You have already read the spreadsheet into a query.  Loop through that query to populate your staging table and carry on processing.

There are a couple of things to look out for with each method.  With Method 1, there might be more than one file to be processed.  Your package will have to handle that.  With Method 2, there might be two users looking to process files at the same time.  You'll have to make sure the two requests don't interfere with each other.

As far as your specific question of "How do I loop through the query and import into an existing table? ", like this:

```
<cfoutput query="yourquery">
<cfquery datasource="something">
insert into atable
(fields go here)
values
(values, using cfqueryparam go here)
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This is what I have currently, bul I get an 'error executing database query' error: <CFQUERY DATASOURCE="#mydatabase#" name="required_db"> insert into temp_dog_upload (dogNameColumn, dogBreedColumn) values ( <cfqueryparam value="#alldoggyQueryResult.dogNameColumnFrom#"> <cfqueryparam value="#alldoggyQueryResult.dogBreedColumn#"> ) </CFQUERY

Comment: I unanswered your question because I needed the <cfloop> for it to work.

Comment: Unanswering is fine, but your reason is not valid.  cfoutput with a query attribute is effectively the same as cfloop with a query attribute.  If you use cfloop, you will still need a cfoutput tag to access the values in that query.  If you take that approach, put your cfloop block inside the cfoutput block.  Otherwise you will be doing extra work inside your loop.

Comment: If all you are doing is inserting records, then you do not need cfoutput.  That said, cfloop versus cfoutput makes no difference. Your original insert query had a syntax error (extra comma) which you most likely fixed.

Comment: *I fixed the comma.* That is what resolved the syntax error. The problem had nothing to do with using cfoutput, unless there is other code in the page you have not shown us.